# Pass variable to laravel method from within the same model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on some multi tenancy updates to a Laravel app but hitting an issue when trying to pass a specific team ID into a method on a model from within another method.

Example:

In Controller:

```
$waitTime = $booking->estimatedWaitTime($teamId);
```

In Booking model:

```
public function queueLength()
{
    $booking = $this->todaysBookings;

    foreach ($bookings as $booking) {
        // Calculate the length of all bookings
    }
}

public function todaysBookings()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserBooking')->whereHas('booking', function ($q) {
        $q->where('team_id', 2);
    });
}
```

This correctly returns the bookings and allows me to loop through them in the queueLength method. However, I want to be able to pass the team_id into the todaysBooking method.

When instead calling todaysBookings as a method:

```
$booking = $this->todaysBookings();
```

It doesn't return anything for me to loop through.

Any ideas how to achieve what I want to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the id as parameter and then get the results :

```
public function todaysBookings($team_id)
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserBooking')->whereHas('booking', function ($q) use($team_id) {
        $q->where('team_id', $team_id);
    });
}
```

In the call you can do as follow :

```
$some_teame_id = 2;
$booking = $this->todaysBookings($some_teame_id)->get();
```

**Why ?**

Because the relationships in laravel serve as powerful query builders ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)) :

> Eloquent relationships are defined as methods on your Eloquent model
>   classes. Since, like Eloquent models themselves, relationships also
>   serve as powerful query builders, defining relationships as methods
>   provides powerful method chaining and querying capabilities.

**[Relationship Methods Vs. Dynamic Properties](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties) :**

The call of the relationship as Methods is needed when you want to add some more conditions and filters like this :

```
$booking->todaysBookings()->where('active', 1)->get(); //just an example :)
```

And if you do not need to add additional constraints to an Eloquent relationship query, you may simply access the relationship as if it were a property, ***Laravel will add the get() for you :)***

```
$booking->todaysBookings
```

Comment: Interesting, when not calling it as a method what is happening differently? Is that 'executing' it so you don't need to call get on it? (Yours works btw, thanks!)

Comment: I will assume you did it twice ;)